# Add a assert for default of Case statement

Tags: c#, unit-testing, code-coverage

I would like to add a assert to test the default condition of case method

Here is the case statement

```
 switch ((a)Enum.Parse(typeof(a), A, true))
        {
            case a.value: return "Int";

            default: throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException("Unrecognized value");
        }
```

Comment: Depends on what unit testing framework you are using, some of them have things like `Assert.Throws<InvalidEnumArgumentException>(() => methodCall())`... But you need to clarify what framework.

Comment: Whatever framework it is, google how to handle exceptions.

Comment: If that's your entire switch statement, you'll never have an invalid name and your default is meaningless. If you removed several cases to obfuscate proprietary enum values, you will need to call it with a different enum value.

Comment: agree with you krillgar. Thanks

Comment: if you're using Enum.Parse it will throw an execption if a string doesn't match the enum names. Use Enum.TryParse instead.